# Is the solution of the initial value problem global?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have an initial value problem where the right hand side is continuous and bounded, is the solution of it global? if yes, does it have to be unique?

I am a beginner in ODE and I really cannot answer this question so some help would be much appreciated. I know about local solutions but I am not good with answering questions regarding global ones.

Comment: Better to add the differential equation to your question.